# Possible to retrieve input from user and running another process?

Tags: c++

Is it possible to use `getline(cin,buffer);` at the top of my program, then have a "animated menu" still running below it? 
For example (very basic):

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 

using namespace std; 
int stringLen=0;
string buffer; 

getline(cin, buffer);

for (int i = 0; i < kMaxWait;i++)
{
     printf("counter waiting for user input %d",i);
     if (1 >= buffer.length())
     break; 
}
```

Would I have to fork that loop somehow so it would keep counting and display the counter until the user enters something??

Comment: Input blocks execution.  You need threads/tasks.

Comment: Why did you tag this with [tag:fork]? You seem to know it's possible using e.g. `fork()`. In general you would use a `std::thread` waiting for changes in the buffer.

Comment: I don't understand fully how fork works, so I wasn't sure if this is a scenario where I would use it

Comment: @Robolisk If you definitely want/need _anoother process_, you can use `fork()` to achieve such behavior, access to `buffer.length()` needs to be synchronized in any case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible answer, given in the comments, is to use threads. But it's not necessary, there's a way to do this without threads.

- Make stdin a non-blocking file descriptor.
- Wait for stdin to become readable, via poll()/select(), in the meantime do your animation, etc...
- Make stdin a blocking file descriptor, again.
- Use std::getline().

There are also some ancillary issues to consider, such as the buffering that comes from `std::streambuf`, so before doing all that, check if there's already something to read from `std::cin`, first.

Comment: So that basically proposes to use the stdin fd in a `select()`/`poll()` loop, right? That's another way.

Comment: I see what you mean, sorta. In a way, the animation block example I gave is very basic. This would actually be a fairly large file doing ascii art type animation in the command window until the user enter data ( Logs in)

Comment: Doesn't matter how extensive. The principle's the same.

Comment: This is a pretty elegant solution actually. Took me a couple of reads before I got there but finally a +1 from me.

Comment: Is this route, or using fork() more efficient?

Comment: @Robolisk: By what metrics?

Answer (score 1):

This is something I used sometime ago. It's quite rudimentary, but you can get the gist of the process - using `poll`. It returns true if there is input, and puts it in `str`, false otherwise. So, you can put this in your loop somewhere, and take action when there is input.

```
bool polled_input(std::string& str)
{
    struct pollfd fd_user_in;
    fd_user_in.fd = STDIN_FILENO;
    fd_user_in.events = POLLIN;
    fd_user_in.revents = 0;

    int rv = poll(&fd_user_in, 1, 0);

    if (rv == -1) {/* error */}
    else if (rv == 0) return false;
    else if (fd_user_in.revents & POLLIN)
    {         
        char buffer[MAX_BUFF_SIZE];
        int rc = read(STDIN_FILENO, buffer, MAX_BUFF_SIZE-1);
        if (rc >= 0) 
        {
            buffer[rc]='\0';
            str = std::string(buffer);
            return true;       
        }
        else {/* error */}
    }        
    else {/* error */}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`select` is meant for this, multiplexed, blocking I/O. It can be done without a `poll` I think:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **arg)
{
   const int time_in_secs = 10;
   const int buffer_size = 1024;
   fd_set readfds;

   FD_ZERO(&readfds);
   FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &readfds);

   struct timeval tv;
   tv.tv_sec = time_in_secs;
   tv.tv_usec = 0;

   int ret = select(STDIN_FILENO + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

   if (!ret)
   {
       std::cout << "Timeout\n";
       exit(1);
   }

   char buf[buffer_size];

   if (FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &readfds))
   {
        int len = read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, buffer_size);
        buf[len] = '\0';
   }

    std::cout << "You typed: " << buf << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```